# Select a datatable value and update it via a shiny widget

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a simple shiny app:

```
#ui.r
navbarPage(
  "Application",
  tabPanel("General",
           sidebarLayout(

             sidebarPanel(
               uiOutput("tex2"),
               uiOutput("book3")
             ),
             mainPanel(
               DT::dataTableOutput("hot3")

             )
           )))
#server.r
  library(shiny)
library(DT)
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  output$tex2<-renderUI({
    numericInput("text2","#tests",
                 value = 1,
                 min=1
    )
  })

  output$book3<-renderUI({

    selectInput("bk3", 
              "Change Name", 
              choices=(paste("Test",1:input$text2)))
  })

  rt1<-reactive({
    data.frame(
      Label=paste("Test",1:input$text2),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  })

  output$hot3 <-DT::renderDataTable(

    rt1(),
    editable = TRUE

  )

}
```

As you can I use the upper `selectInput()` in order to add or remove a new test in the second `selectinput()` and in the table. What I want is to select a row drom the datatable (for example "Test 1") and then be able to edit this specific `selectInput()` value ("Test 1" to "Test ABC") and this value will be displayed in the table as "Test ABC". Basically I do not know if this functionality is even possible (editing a `selectInput()` choice) or a textInput() might be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

I would include two `req(input$text2)` in the `renderUI` and in the `reactive`. To edit the Labels in the Table, you just have to double-click the item and change the name.

```
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  output$tex2<-renderUI({
    numericInput("text2","#tests",
                 value = 1,
                 min=1
    )
  })

  output$book3<-renderUI({
    req(input$text2)

    selectInput("bk3", 
                "Change Name", 
                choices=(paste("Test",1:input$text2)))
  })

  rt1<-reactive({
    req(input$text2)

    data.frame(
      Label=paste("Test",1:input$text2),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  })

  output$hot3 <-DT::renderDataTable(
    rt1(),
    editable = TRUE
  )
}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry I guess my question is not clear enough. First I want to select a row from the table which will include "test 1" for example, then I should edit it from the widget and then this updated value will be displayed in the table. Tnx for your answer anyway.

Comment: Edit it from which widget? I suppose you mean from the Table. The updated value is visible in the Table but not in the selectInput. Do you mean it should be updated there too?

Comment: yes ideally I would update it in the selectInput box and then It would be upadted in the table. I suppose this is not possible.

Comment: It could be a textInput not a selectInput I guess